# Большинство программ в андроиде не имеют кнопку выхода, как они "закрываются"?

Tags: android

Если открыть какую-нибудь программу в android, потом захотеть закрыть программу, то в большинстве случаев, нет кнопки выйти. Когда программу закрываешь, она может быть свернута по факту или закрыта совсем. Как android понимает что приложение свернуто, но не закрыто полностью?

P.S. Прошу прощения, за возможно глупый вопрос, который плохо сформулирован, но я хочу понять суть и принцип работы.

Comment: у приложения просто нет понятия "приложение свернуто". Поэтому и проблемы нет.

Comment: если нет, то что висит в работающих приложениях если приложение не открыто?

Comment: горячий резерв. По факту, после "сворачивания" приложение может работать, а может и не работать. Все зависит от квалификации разработчика.

Если нужна работа в фоне - используются сервисы.

Comment: @KoVadim Ага, работа в фоне значит с использованием сервисов. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой [статье](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/60-urok-23-activity-lifecycle-v-kakih-sostojanijah-mozhet-byt-activity.html) написано в каких состояниях может быть активити.

Comment: Вот по ссылке хорошо написано.


    Обычно в учебниках эта тема дается по-другому. Но мне это шаблонное объяснение кажется недостаточно понятным, поэтому я написал свое. Как всегда, надеюсь, что у меня получилось раскрыть тему )

автор прав (наверное, поскольку на самом деле я с андроидом не знаком).

Answer (score 3):

Вы неправильно понимаете понятия "приложение" и графическое представление приложения на экране, которое реализуется с помощью Activity. Приложение может работать и никак себя не показывать на экране.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: @Free_ze, опередил.

Comment: На самом деле, понять как переходы между состояниями в этой схеме связаны с органами (в т.ч. "картинками" на тачскрине) управления девайсом -- невозможно.

Видимо поэтому, рассказать простыми словами никто не может.

Comment: @avp Вы, наверное, просто не обратили внимание на то, что некоторые ветви подписаны фразой, начинающейся с "User...". Вот они и должны натолкнуть на мысль, что под этим скрываются некоторые пользовательские действия. Если человек интересуется "как оно работает", зачем от него скрывать важные детали (коими являются состояния)?

Comment: @avp И что может быть непонятно, даже обывателю, в этих четырех состояниях?

Comment: @Free_ze, вот я андроидом не занимаюсь, и мне совершенно непонятно, какие события (действия пользователя, обмен по сети, таймер и т.п.) какие переходы *из состояний* `onPause()` и `onStop()` вызывают.

Comment: @avp Эм...я андроидом тоже не занимаюсь, но приставка "on" мне говорит о том, что это как миниум обработчик, а не состояние. Да и скобки, подчеркивающие функциональный вызов, здесь не просто так нарисованы.

Comment: @avp Троллятор вы знатный =) Вопрос стоял о том, откуда ОС узнает состояние программы. Я ответил картинкой на тему жизненного пути активити. Вы мне начали впаривать про то, что происходит между  состояниями. Не надо так!